# How could I travel back in time and tell a lie to myself? And how could I tell if future me was lying?

Tags: time-travel, psychology, communication, prophecy

Hypothetical scenario.  At the end of last semester, I got okay grades in my courses.  Not great, but passable.  Let's say that today I somehow come across a time machine; I'm not able or willing to help my past self cheat outright (test questions, homework solutions, etc.), but I *can* give him a little motivation; I go back in time to last August and tell him that if he doesn't get his act together, he will screw up **bad** and lose out on a job offer.

Of course, my past self has thought of this very same issue before.  He is, after all, a savvy Worldbuilding reader.  I am quickly able to convince past me that yes, I am indeed him six months into the future.  But, here's the problem; **past me is just as much a skeptic as present me is.**  How does he know that I didn't come back in time to lie to him?  How will I know that past me will walk away and ultimately do nothing (or worse, get lazier) because he thinks I'm exaggerating or stretching the truth a bit?

So, my question is ultimately this: **How could I go back in time to the recent past (under a year) and convince past me of some lie?**  Also, **how could past me determine that present me is lying or exaggerating?**

Comment: Hi Jesse, welcome to Worldbuilding. As much as I wish I could go back to give some hints to my past self, that question isn't about Worldbuilding, but it is about the actions of a single individual. And as such, I think it is off-topic. You can read more about it on the [tour] or [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If future me found a time machine and the only thing he could think to do with it is come back and hassle me about my grades, I'd take that pretty seriously.

Comment: 'Let's go get two do-dos and force them to make out!'

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question lies in another question, "Under what conditions would a future version of a person give bad advice to their younger self?"

I don't think it matters if the future you is lying or not.  The issue is not absoulute truthfullness.  This is an issue of insight and intent.  If the future you is actually from the future that you are currently heading towards, then their insight (i.e. their understanding of the consequences of your current life) will be greater than your own.  Which leaves the question of their intent.

Are you a self-hating masocist who upon finding some happiness later in life, might travel back in time to steer younger you away from it?

If not, don't worry about whether future you is lying.  Accept whatever they tell you as gospel and get to work!

---one more thought---

Don't assume that future you has the same goals as you do.  Imagine that instead of studying tonight, you go to the corner store and buy a lottery ticket and that a few days later, you are a millionaire.  Future you may already have learned the hard way, that you are not qualified to drive a ferrari at top speed.  Future you might also know that the love of your life, whom you are currently dating, has an aversion to wearing safety belts.  Future you's suggestions may have nothing to do with fixing your grades or getting some fictional future job.  They may just want to keep you way from that corner store and by extension out of some non-fictional wrecked and blood covered ferrari.

Comment: When I have a time machine I will go back in time to screw with my past self to vent my anger for that guy from the future who destroyed my life with bad advise when I was younger.

Comment: II'm going to go forward in time, come back with some futuristic technology, and sell it. Humanity, and my pocketbook, are all felling like they got a bargain.

Comment: Future you might be suicidal.

Comment: @HowardMiller, I almost covered that contingency in my answer, mentioning suicidal tendencies when I was asking about masocism.  Now I know I was wrong to not include it in my answer.  Thanks for adding it here!

Answer (score 1):

Use make-up to make yourself look much older (but still recognizable). Then tell your past self that you are not just from 6 month from the future but actually 10 or 20 years.

This gives you far more authority, because your past self will assume:

- That you have turned much wiser over the years
- That you can judge the impact of current decisions much better because you don't just know the immediate consequences, but the consequences they will have years from now on. Saying "you will lose a job 6 months from now" doesn't have nearly as much impact as "you won't find any decent job for the next 10 years".
- That you've changed over the years, so his/her knowledge about himself/herself won't apply to you anymore